# Simple Rotating frame of reference

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, inertial-frames, relative-motion

I have a car moving in straight line with certain time-varying acceleration and there is another car moving in a curvilinear way along some curved path with some time-varying acceleration. The inertial reference frame is say fixed at some point in space. The relative velocity and acceleration at any instant is calculated.

- Why is the relative velocity of the car moving in curved path from the point of view of the car moving in straightline, different from the relative velocity of the car moving in straightline from the point of view of the car moving in the curved path?

I know that in mathematical formulation this will involve the instantaneous angular velocity of the car following the curved path. But that is not very intuitive to me. Is there any way I can understand this situation clearly and more intuitively,i.e., Visualize it.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It isn't different. The relative velocities are the same from either observer.

Comment: Are you sure? The second car is moving in a curved path so there will be a rotation effect for sure.

Comment: The direction of the relative velocity vector will rotate even if you take it between a straight line and one point that doesn't lie on the line. Maybe I don't quite understand, yet, what you are trying to ask.

Comment: What I meant to say is the local coordinate fixed on the second car moving along the curved path is rotating with respect to the centre of rotation.

Comment: Yes, but working in a non-inertial system has no consequences on the velocity vector. It will cause fictitious forces to appear, which is why Newton's laws are only valid in inertial systems. The relative velocity is not impacted.

Comment: Please look at the posted examples

Comment: Ah! Now I see what you mean. The physical vector is (up to a choice of sign) the same, but the coordinate representation of the vector is different. That's correct. Different choice of coordinate systems will lead to different representations of the same vector. For your aviation example that's a truly vital to understand complication of non-scalar physical quantities.

Comment: But physically does it means that the way the car in straightline feels the velocity of car in the curve, is different from the the way the car in the curve feels for the car in straightline? It's mathematically correct..But little counterintuitive

Comment: Anyway to convince myself that it is indeed the case?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33949/discussion-between-curiousone-and-archangel89).

Comment: The representation of the vector in coordinates is just numbers that depend on the choice of coordinate system base vectors. If the coordinate base vectors change, so will the numbers, even if the vector that they represent is the same. It's something that you have to get used to... there is the physical quantity (the vector) and then there are the numbers that represent it in your calculation after you choose your coordinate system. Look at it this way: the numbers can't kill you... the vector can. That's the way to distinguish a physical quantity from its representation.

Comment: But how can the magnitude be different in each case? If the magnitude is different surely I must be feeling it differently if I travel in a rotational frame than a translating frame?

Comment: You can't feel velocity, only acceleration. Of course there will be some acceleration felt in the plane on the  circular path, but it has nothing to do with the relative velocity vectors between the two planes.